# Is there a global forall construct in SMT language or a Z3 extension?

Tags: constraints, z3, solver, smt

The global variables are treated as existentially quantified by default. E.g.

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (exists ((y Int)) (and (= x y) (= x y))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Gives

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y!0 () Int
    0)
  (define-fun x () Int
    0)
)
```

How do I get it to treat `x` as `forall x`, like in this query:

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (exists ((y Int)) (and (= x y) (= x y)))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

To get the value `y` depend on `x`:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y!0 ((x!1 Int)) Int
    x!1)
)
```

That should be just a matter of syntax. Is it possible in z3? In another SMT solver?

## Edit:

What I want to achieve, is to execute the script like:

```
(declare-forall-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (and (= x y) (= x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

And get the response like:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y!0 ((x!1 Int)) Int
    x!1)
)
```

In other words, I want to declare the "forall" parameter globally, and refer to it in subsequent assertions.

Comment: To get Z3 to treat `x` as universal, you add a `forall` quantifier, just as you suggest. So, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, I want to introduce many such variables `x1`, `x2`, ..., step-by-step, not in a single `assert`. So I want to build the query incrementally introducing conditions and variables(both existential and universal) to the context one after another

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is. Note that you can use multiple quantifiers, e.g. (forall (exists (forall (exists ....)))).

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, the problem is in building the query step-by step by supplying many asserts and declarations gradually filling the z3 context. I want to take advantage of the z3 `push`/`pop` directives, and run a single solver instance for multiple similar queries (the way people usually do [symbex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution) verification)

Comment: Yes, that's fine and you can build your queries incrementally and you can use push/pop. I still don't see what the problem is. Is there anything that doesn't work?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, yes. I can not push the `forall x` definition.

Comment: How are you trying to do that? Asserting a formula that contains quantifiers is no different from adding assertions without quantifiers. Note that (push n) takes an integer, not an assertion (it's the number of scopes you want to push).

Comment: Also, both of your scripts work just fine, they do exactly what they should do, except perhaps that y!0 could be removed from the model. What do you expect them to return?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, I expanded the question. Basically I want a `declare-forall-const` global `forall` declaration, just like the `declare-const` is a global `exists` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. In an SMT solver, all outermost variables are existential, but nobody forces you to use only outermost variables. If you have only one quantifier scope, a popular approach is to negate the query, i.e., instead of checking satisfiability of `forall x . phi(x)` you can check for unsatisfiability of `exists x . not phi(x)`.